# Getting a continuous chain of values based on a condition in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Say I have a `List` of numbers:

```
var list = new List<int>{100, 1, 2, 4, 10, 11, 50, 54};
```

And I want the output to be sets of numbers that satisfy a condition of "closeness" with its adjacent values.

So for example, if I define the distance between adjacent numbers to be less than `5`, I will get something like:

```
Set1: {100}
Set2: {1, 2, 4}
Set3: {10, 11}
Set4: {50, 54}
```

Since the numbers in each set are within `5` of its adjacent value.

How would I do this in LINQ? I was thinking of some combination of `Aggregate()` and `TakeWhile()` but I couldn't figure it out.

To be clear, I am looking for a generic way of solving this (i.e. an algorithm that if I change 5 to any other number would also give an output of sets that satisfy the new condition).

Comment: following fubo above, it looks like the example doesn't match the description. The distance between 4 and 10 is < 10, so should the groups be {100}, {1,2,4,10,11}, {50,55} ? or are you trying to group them in decades (as ASh below)

Comment: @AlanT you are right I have reedited my question. The distance should be 5 instead.

Comment: Do you need to use `Linq`? It seems that a sort and iterate through would be simplest.

Comment: @AlanT Actually no, although I would think that Linq would produce a neater solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure there are better approaches, since you want to do it with `Linq` you could do something like this.

```
int gid=0, prevvalue = list[0];
va result =  list.Select(x=>
    {
        var obj =  Math.Abs(prevvalue-x)>=10? 
                     new {gid= ++gid, item =x} 
                    :new {gid= gid, item =x};
        prevvalue= x;           
        return obj;
    })
    .GroupBy(x=>x.gid)
    .Select(x=>x.Select(s=>s.item).ToList())
    .ToArray();
```

Check this [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BxK01o)